# What happens when non-void method reaches end in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, return

**Question** I'd like to ask what happens when a non-void method reaches end without return?

**Environment** This question is related to `iOS` and `Objective-C`. I'm not sure how things described in this question behave elsewhere.

---

**Introduction and background**

Normally, when you declare a non-void method in Objective-C and you don't specify a `return`, Xcode shows a compile error

`Control reaches end of non-void function`

and forbids you from compiling unless you fix this issue.

The system can be very smart in detecting if your code can or cannot reach an end of non-void function - recognizing if your if/else blocks satisfy all options, going through switches etc.

However, I've found one (and there may be others, really) options of brain-f**king the compiler into thinking "Hey mate, yeah, this code looks perfectly fine, let's compile it and have fun!". It was by accident and caused some head-aches. Here's the code!

**The Code**

```
typedef enum eSections { eSectionRecent, eSectionAround, eSectionAll } eSections;

...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger localSection = section;
    if (numberOfSections == 2) localSection++;

    switch ((eSections)@(localSection))
    {
        case eSectionRecent:
            return 1;
            break;
        case eSectionAround:
            return 1;
            break;
        case eSectionAll:
            return 3;
            break;
    }
}
```

**The Result**

With this code, the compiler *thinks* that it's ok to let this method compile, because *hey, there's the switch object which is an enum, and there is a case for each of the possible enum values, so, yeah, that sounds legit*...

So I'm really interested, what happens now that the compiler was confused and let me run this faulty code to the end?

**The Error**

For anyone interested, my error was in `(eSections)@(localSection)`, where instead of typing `localSection` into eSections I typed `@(localSection)`, which compiles into a `NSNumber` and instead of the value uses the pointer to the object, thus failing to match with any of the the `case`, since pointers can be quite long (and very probably not 0, 1 or 2). What happened next was that the project tried to allocate space for a really huge number of cells (I think that not specifying a return was something like *let's just throw some memory value there*) and ultimately crashed the app for memory pressure.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: You could as well ask: what happens when I access uninitialized pointers.

Comment: you will get a peace of junk, since compiler cant protect you anymore.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would down vote this question. It's actually one of the better asked questions I've seen here in a while. It's clear, it shows good effort, and it has a clear example of the issue. There is no basis for a down vote.

Comment: Learn assembly language.

Comment: Any request for improvements from the down-voters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is undefined behavior.

Usually, the caller gets unspecified junk as the return value. Whatever was left in the register or, in some cases, some stack location used by the caller for a local variable is what the caller gets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wonder, is it a SDK bug that I'm able to compile the mentioned code and (potentially) publish it to AppStore? As that's why I think the normal-case compiler *error*, not warning, of "Control reaches end of non-void function" is there. Also, do you have any proof/more explanation for the "... or, in some cases, some stack location..." statement? I'd be really super interested in going deeper here!

Comment: It's not a bug in the tools. C and Objective-C allow you, the programmer, to shoot yourself in the foot. A type cast expression is you telling the compiler that an expression **is** of a certain type even if it doesn't seem so. So, it compiles as though that were so. The compiler *could* report an error whenever it is theoretically possible that a function reaches the end of a non-void function, but that would force us to add default cases or extraneous `return` statements in cases where we know that it's not actually possible. It's a trade-off.